# I installed by mistake MySQL version 10.5.0-MariaDB is EOL software, what should I do now server is in production?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos8

I've installed MySQL version 10.5.0-MariaDB is EOL software by mistake what should I do now server in production? What should i do ? wait for a new release since everything seems to be working fine. 
Or what you guys suggest ?

Is it even possible to downgrade to 10.4 stable considering this is a production server with a database on it ?

I have CentOS 8, php 7.4 but mariadb 10.5 the eol software :(

Answer (score 2):

As of January 2020, [MariaDB 10.5 is the alpha (development, preview) version](https://mariadb.org/download/#release-schedule).  EOL stands for end of life, it is not that.  10.3 is a version on the CentOS 8 AppStream, that is a stable release.

[Downgrading MariaDB is not supported.](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/downgrading-between-major-versions-of-mariadb/) A safe thing to do is to keep running this preview version, and watch for any problems. Unlikely anything too bad would be in even an alpha release, but normally these are installed to test databases first.

Fix your processes that resulted in installing undesirable versions to production. `yum install mariadb-server` would not have done this. And every link on the MariaDB KB says that 10.5 is alpha. What did you do?

Comment: i installed 10.5 cuz i thought that was the latest stable version. only to late i release i was running on an alpha version

Comment: And when 10.5.xx is announced as "General Availablity" upgrade to it.